# mongodb log can I empty this file without error

Tags: mongodb, logging

Can I empty the log file without spoiling the installation?
I do not want to erase it.
I have the installation in linux, if so, how could I do it?

Answer (score 18):

There are a couple of options. Probably the best way is to [rotate the log file](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/rotate-log-files/), for example via the mongo shell:

```
use admin
db.runCommand( { logRotate : 1 } )
```

You can also send a signal to the mongod process, this won't kill the process, it will just signal it to perform the rotation. Run from the linux shell:

```
kill -SIGUSR1 <mongod pid>
```

Another option to "clear" the existing log is to run (specify full path or run from the same directory as the log file):

```
cp /dev/null mongod.log
```